# Events trigger after next click in Google Tag manager preview

Tags: google-tag-manager

My custom event does populate into my GA4 Analytics, but during testing, the events in the GTM preview don't show up until the next click after the triggering event.

Oddly, it seems that after the initial trigger of each event (with the followup click) they appear to

For the follow-up click, I can click anywhere on the page.

The trigger is set to "All Elements" and Firing when the element matches a CSS selector of [data-XXX="XXX"] and the page URL contains a keyword.

I'm concerned that due to the extra click needed I may be losing some non-zero portion of data. My site doesn't get too many of this particular event so every one counts. The event tracks our online reservation and I need it to be accurate in our Google Ads data so our ROI on ad spend is as accurate as possible.

I know there's a trigger on form submit, but the form doesn't actually trigger this way due to JS. And it does work with the "All Elements" trigger I'm just concerned about the extra click before I see it populate in the preview window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After closer inspection I found that the followup click is not required.

The summary view does not appear to show ALL info for every single click in realtime. Instead if you choose to look into the data for each click as the happen you can see that the events are triggering as intended, but that new events don't always show in the summary view until after the next click registers.

Hopefully, a future GTM update may fix this as it is not intuitive that the summary view would ever not have the most current data.

TLDR: check the view for each click in the GMT preview and don't rely solely on the summary view.